# Error en eliminacion de registros

Tags: php, javascript

Intendo hacer un eliminacion de registros de una tabla con php y javascript, pero al momento de hacer la eliminacion aveces la hace y otras veces no

Este es el codigo de mi boton

```js
 <button title="Eliminar Registro" id="delete-contrato-modal" name="delete-contrato-modal" type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-danger btn-just-icon remove" onclick="deleteCbContrato('<?php echo($row_herramientas['id_tipo_contrato']); ?>');"><i class="material-icons" data-target="#myModalDelete01" data-toggle="modal" >close</i></button>
```

Esta es la funcion

```js
function deleteCbContrato(id_tipo_contrato){     
        $('#id_tipo_contratoDelete').val(id_tipo_contrato);           

        $('#myModalDelete01').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#myInput01').focus()
        }); 
}
```

Este es mi modal

```js
<!-- Modal DELETE -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalDelete01" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalDeleteLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">

                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>


                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalDeleteLabel">Eliminación de Registro</h4>
                    </div>
                    <form role="form" name="formDeleteContrato" method="post">
                        <div class="modal-body">                                    
                                <div class="input-group">
                                <label for="id_tipo_contrato">¿Desea eliminar el registro seleccionado?</label>
                                </div>       
                                <div class="input-group">
                                 <label for="id_tipo_contrato">Registro: </label>
                                 <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="id_tipo_contratoDelete" name="id_tipo_contratoDelete" >                                        
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="delete-contrato-select" name="delete-contrato-select" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>                                        
                     <button id="cancel"type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>   



                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal --> 

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#delete-contrato-select').on("click", function(){

var r01=$('#id_tipo_contratoDelete').val();

                "r_delete01" : r01
var parametros = {
        };
        $.ajax({
                data:  parametros,
                url:   'includes/funciones_catalogos.php',
                type:  'post',
                beforeSend: function () {

                },
                success:  function (response) {
location.reload();
                }
        });
 });

</script>
```

Y aqui esta la accion del Delete

```js
<?php
require_once('../conex/conex.php'); 

if(isset($_POST['r_delete01']))
{

$sql01=mysqli_query($conex,"DELETE FROM tipo_contrato WHERE id_tipo_contrato=".$_POST['r_delete01']);
 $conex->query($sql01);
}else{}
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida. Evita usar fragmentos de código para contenido que no se puede probar aquí. En cuanto al problema en sí: ¿da algún error? Has verificado que el `WHERE` sí se cumple cuando no funciona? ¿Has verificado si el `DELETE` violaría alguna restricción y queda bloqueado por eso? ¿Estás capturando los errores en el `else` o lo tienes así tal cual, en blanco? Si pones esto en el `else`  te dirá lo que ocurre: `}else{ echo mysqli_error($conex);}` Pero debes poner `cosole.log(response);`  en el `success`  de Ajax y revisar la consola.  O poner `alert(response);`

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias, es que soy nuevo en la pagina, y tambien estoy empezando a programar , no no me marca ningun error solo que aveces si hace el delete y otras no. No no eh hecho esas verificaciones, tampoco se si se violaria alguna restriccion con el delete y si silo tengo el else en blanco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay problemas tanto en el código PHP como en el código Javascript

### PHP:

Tu código se ejecuta dos veces ya que esto:

```
$sql01=mysqli_query($conex,"DELETE FROM tipo_contrato WHERE id_tipo_contrato=".$_POST['r_delete01']);
```

Y esto:

```
$conex->query($sql01);
```

Es lo mismo.

Vamos a corregirlo, y usaremos el estilo orientado a objetos, es mucho más claro y entendible. Además:

- Vamos a escribir un código seguro usando consultas preparadas
- Vamos a controlar la variable del POST
- Y vamos a establecer un control de errores

Propongo esto:

```
<?php
$dato=(empty($_POST['r_delete01'])) ? NULL: $_POST['r_delete01'];
if ($dato)
{
    require_once('../conex/conex.php');
    $sqlDelete="DELETE FROM tipo_contrato WHERE id_tipo_contrato=?";
    $stmt=$conex->prepare($sqlDelete);
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$dato);
    if($stmt->execute())
    {
        $totalDeleted=$conex->affected_rows;
        $msg="Se borraron $totalDeleted filas";
    }else{
        $msg="Hubo un error: ".$conex->error;
    }
}else{
    $msg="No hay datos en el POST";
}
echo $msg;
```

---

### Javascript

Estás enviando la variable `parametros` vacía al servidor, al construirla así:

```
                "r_delete01" : r01  //Esto está fuera
var parametros = {                  //Aquí dentro no hay nada 
        };
```

Para que los valores estén dentro debes ponerlos así:

```
var parametros = { 
                   "r_delete01" : r01 
                 };
```

Sólo para mostrar lo ocurrido, puedes poner esto en el código Javascript:

```
success:  function (response) {
    /*Agregas esto*/
    alert(response);
    location.reload();
```

También puedes poner: `console.log(response);`, aunque para verlo tendrás que revisar la consola. Aquí como es una cadena lo verás en el `alert`, si fuera un objeto, como un JSON por ejemplo, no lo podrás ver con `alert`, tendrás que usar la consola.

Comment: Ya lo hice como me recomiendas pero sigue sin hacer la eliminacion del registo, solo muestra el mensaje de que no hay datos

Comment: @Tallulah claro, tus parámetros están vacíos porque los datos están fuera. Ponlo así: **`var parametros = { "r_delete01" : r01 };`** Los valores en tu código están fuera de las llaves `{   }`, por lo que estás enviando *nada*  al servidor.

Comment: Ya lo corregi , pero de igual manera solo elimina aveces

Comment: @Tallulah ¿y cuando no elimina que imprime, que se borraron `0`  filas?  ¿O imprime otra cosa?

Comment: imprime "Se borraron 1 filas" pero no hace la eliminacion

Comment: Heyyyy no me lo puedo creer que el manejador mienta :) ¿Estás seguro de que no se hizo la eliminación?  ¿No será que hay varios duplicados del mismo registro? ¿Por qué dices que no se hace la eliminación @Tallulah? Cuenta las filas antes y después del `DELETE` y sabrás si está borrando o no. No creo que `affected_rows` diga que se borró una fila sin ser cierto.

Comment: Es que ingreso varios registros para hacer pruebas, pero ingreso 3 registros y de esos 3 me elimina nada mas 2 . La tabla tiene pocos registros asi es que no hay registros repetidos, es el ultimo registro el que no me quiere eliminar

Comment: No entiendo bien tu último comentario @Tallulah. Es muy fácil saber si está borrando o no: cuenta los registros antes y después de probar el código. Lo puedes hacer en el mismo código si quieres. Es raro que no los borre a no ser que la tabla tenga alguna restricción o que haya otros usuarios creando registros en la misma tabla.

Comment: Me refiero a que estoy haciendo pruebas para verificar que elimine, e ingreso 3 registros a la tabla, pero de esos 3 registros solo elimina dos y el ultimo registro que ingrese es el que no quiere eliminar, no se si me doy a entender ahora?

Comment: Tu consulta tiene un `WHERE id_tipo_contrato=EL-NUMERO-QUE-ESCRIBAS`, si tú ingresas tres registros con ese mismo número en la columna `id_tipo_contrato` deberían eliminarse, a no ser que haya alguna restricción a nivel de la tabla.  Prueba sino en la base de datos misma. Y prueba a imprimir las variables. Debes estar haciendo algo mal, no puede ser que no elimine si la condición se cumple.

Comment: Comprobe eliminarlo directamente desde el manejador de base de datos, y si elimina pero despues entro a la pagina y la recargo y me vuelve a aparecer el registro a la base de datos

Comment: Pues a ver si no estás usando dos tablas o dos bases de dato distintas o algo así, porque eso que dices es mássss raro todavía. No puede ser que lo hayas eliminado y te aparezca por el otro lado. Podría ser la caché del navegador, pero es muy raro ese comportamiento tratándose de la base de datos.

Comment: Pues es la unica base de datos que tengo, mm... pues la verdad no se que podria ser

Comment: No sabría que más decirte @Tallulah. Muestra un `SHOW CREATE TABLE tipo_contrato`  a ver si la columma es de otro tipo. Recuerdo un caso así extraño donde la columna era del tipo `ENUM`.

Comment: Creo que ya se que era el problema tenia conflicto con un isset

Comment: ¿Conflicto con un `isset`?  No entiendo. En mi solución he sacado de circulación el  `isset`, @Tallulah

Comment: Es que cuando se recargaba la pagina se activaba el isset pero de una consulta de insert y se el otro no lo ejecutaba y habia ese conflicto

Comment: @Tallulah, me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.

Comment: Ah claro muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Adicionalmente al comentario de *A. Cedano*, no estás ejecutando el código PHP al hacer click en el botón. La función que recibe el evento click no hace nada más que asignar un valor al elemento `#id_tipo_contratoDelete`, y la forma de la pantalla modal no tiene definido el atributo `action`. Para ejecutar la eliminación del registro, debés enviar la forma o hacer un llamado asíncrono (ver [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)) al PHP que ejecuta la eliminación al hacer click en el botón submit de la forma, o bien establecer una acción para la forma:

```
function deleteCbContrato(id_tipo_contrato){     
    $('#id_tipo_contratoDelete').val(id_tipo_contrato);

    // Ya veremos algo sobre este bloque de código
    $('#myModalDelete01').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#myInput01').focus()
    }); 
}

$(function (){
    $('form[name=formDeleteContrato]').on('submit', function() {
        $.post({
            url: "tu_archivo_php.php",
            data: {r_delete01: id_tipo_contrato},
            success: function(resultado) {
                alert(resultado);
            });
    });
});
```

O bien:

```
                <!-- Establecer ruta del action de la forma -->
                <form role="form" name="formDeleteContrato" method="post" action="tu_archivo_php.php">
                    <div class="modal-body">                                    
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <label for="id_tipo_contrato">¿Desea eliminar el registro seleccionado?</label>
                            </div>       
                            <div class="input-group">
                             <label for="id_tipo_contrato">Registro: </label>
                             <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="id_tipo_contratoDelete" name="id_tipo_contratoDelete" >                                        
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="delete-contrato-select" name="delete-contrato-select" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>                                        
                 <button id="cancel"type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>   



                    </div>
                </form>
```

El bloque `$('#myModalDelete01').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){...})` lo que hace es ligar la función `function(){$('#myInput01').focus()}` al evento `shown.bs.modal` **cada vez** que se ejecuta la función `deleteCbContrato()`. Lo correcto es sacar ese bloque de código de la función y ponerla en el `$(function(){})`, algo así:

```
$(function(){
    ...
    $('#myModalDelete01').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#myInput01').focus()
    });
    ... 
});
```